# Looking for an UWP Grid that has ItemsSource

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I am looking for a control that can handle ItemsSource, like a ListVIew, but at the same time handles automatic column width.

- Grid doesn't seem to handle `ItemsSource`, so dynamically adding rows would mean a lot of column definitions.
- ListView doesn't understand a mix of `Auto` and `*` columns, so gives strange results.
- DataGrid seems to be the closest possible thing, but has many features that I don't want. Like row selection and focus items.

I tried to use the DataGrid, but there are just too many features. Are there any DataGrid implementations or other controls available in UWP that simply let me fill a grid with ItemsSource that are only used for layout? Or should I continue on this path and try to disable as many features as I can via styles?

[image: Example of DataGrid]

```xml
<tkControls:DataGrid
    AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" <!-- doesn't seem to work -->
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind _viewModel.Modes, Mode=OneWay}">
    <tkControls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <tkControls:DataGridTextColumn
            Width="*"
            Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Record">
            <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:IModeViewModel">
                    <CheckBox
                        IsChecked="{x:Bind IsRecordEnabled}"
                        IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsStrongestMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolNegationConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150">
            <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:IModeViewModel">
                    <controls:QuantityBox
                        IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsGainEditEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
                        PropertySettings="{x:Bind GainPropertySettings, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Quantity="{x:Bind Gain}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View">
            <tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:IModeViewModel">
                    <CheckBox
                        IsChecked="{x:Bind IsVisible}"
                        IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsRecordEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tkControls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </tkControls:DataGrid.Columns>
</tkControls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why would "dynamically adding rows would mean a lot of column definitions"? You onlu need a column definition per column that you indent to display regardless of the number of rows.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right about that. But Grid still doesn't support ItemsSource for dynamically adding rows via xaml, right?

Comment: No, but you could use an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: @mm8 I tried making use of ItemsControl and Grid, but I cannot use all Auto and * columns, because I won't be able to synchronize the header widths with the item widths. Do you have a solution to sync the widths of the HeaderTemplate with the ItemsTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can't have too many features, they trend to be useful someday ...

Stating that, you are on the right track. Use the datagrid and disable/style anything you need. For the selection and focusing you may use

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!--Other DataGrid items-->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Putting `IsHitTestVisible` to false makes that all controls are disabled as well, so it would be impossible to click the checkboxes for example.

Comment: Alas, if you like your controls still to be editable, then what's the point of hiding the focus frame. That makes it harder for those using keyboard navigation. However, you can still you can use styling to hide the visisble selection masks.